# Duplicate entries in SQL Server using C# ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

This code is duplicating entries in the SQL Server database. There 2 entries for every submission.

I can't see where it's happening. I've tried multiple things, like moving the `conn.Close()`, but nothing I've tried helps.

I looked at the [`SqlTransaction` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqltransaction?view=netframework-4.5) info, and it's close to that, but doesn't have the "using" part...

Would it help to break it up, I'm not sure how? I'm still a newbie, and grateful for any help!

```
public partial class _default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=*****;Initial Catalog=****;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=******;Password=*******");

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtRequestor.Focus();
    }

    protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime dtToday = DateTime.Now;
        SmtpClient server = new SmtpClient("*********", 25);
        server.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;

        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
        mail.To.Add(txtRequestorsEmail.Text);
        mail.From = new MailAddress("*******", "name");
        mail.Subject = ("Hardware Request for ") + txtRequestor.Text;

        mail.Body = "<span style='font-size: 16px; font-family:Cambria Math'>";

        mail.Body += Bold("Hardware Request submitted by: ") + Red(txtRequestor.Text);

        mail.Body += Bold("<br>Date submitted: ") + dtToday;

        mail.Body += Bold("<br>Building: ") + Red(ddlBuilding.SelectedValue);

        mail.Body += Bold("<br>Room Number: ") + Red(txtRoomNo.Text);

        mail.Body += Bold("<br>Administrator's Email: ") + Red(ddlAdministrator.SelectedValue);

        mail.Body += Bold("<br><br>Type of Request: ") + Red(rblRequestType.Text);

        mail.Body += Bold("<br>Device Requested: ") + Red(rblRequestDevice.Text);

        mail.Body += Bold("<br><br>Description of Request: ") + Red(txtDescription.Value);

        mail.Body += Bold("<br><br>YOU WILL RECEIVE STATUS EMAILS AS YOUR REQUEST IS PROCESSED");

        mail.Body += "</span>";

        try
        {
            server.Send(mail);
            ErrorAlert("Request successfully submitted, if you do not receive a confirmation email please check the address try again.");
            ClearInputs(Page.Controls);
        }
        catch (Exception E)
        {
            ErrorAlert(E.Message);
        }

        //Add the values to the database

        var strRequestor = Request.Form["txtRequestor"];
        var strEmail = Request.Form["txtRequestorsEmail"];
        var strBuilding = Request.Form["ddlBuilding"];
        var strRoom = Request.Form["txtRoomNo"];
        var strAdmin = Request.Form["ddlAdministrator"];
        var strRequestType = Request.Form["rblRequestType"];
        var strRequestDevice = Request.Form["rblRequestDevice"];
        var strDescription = Request.Form["txtDescription"];

        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
        SqlTransaction trx;

        trx = conn.BeginTransaction();

        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.Transaction = trx;

        try
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Requests (RequestDate, RequestorsName, RequestorsEmail, BuildingName, BuildingRoom, AdministratorEmail, RequestType, RequestDevice, RequestDescription) OUTPUT INSERTED.ID VALUES ('" + dtToday + "','" + strRequestor + "','" + strEmail + "','" + strBuilding + "','" + strRoom + "','" + strAdmin + "','" + strRequestType + "','" + strRequestDevice + "','" + strDescription + "')";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            trx.Commit();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblError.Text = "Exception Type: {0} " + ex.GetType() + " Message: {0}" + ex.Message;

            try
            {
                trx.Rollback();
            }
            catch (Exception ex2)
            {
                lblError.Text += " Rollback error: " + ex2.Message;
            }
        }

        int id = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

        var domain = "***********";
        var sb = new StringBuilder("<br><br>Please click ");
        sb.AppendFormat("<a href='{0}/adminapproval.aspx?id={1}'> here</a> to approve or deny the request", domain, id);
        var content = sb.ToString();
        MailMessage mail2 = new MailMessage();
        mail2.IsBodyHtml = true;
        mail2.To.Add(strAdmin);
        mail2.From = new MailAddress("********", "name");
        mail2.Subject = ("Hardware Request for ") + strBuilding + " needs Approval";

        mail2.Body = "<span style='font-size: 16px; font-family:Cambria Math'>";

        mail2.Body += Bold("Hardware Request submitted by: ") + Red(strRequestor);

        mail2.Body += Bold("<br>Date submitted: ") + dtToday;

        mail.Body += Bold("<br>Building: ") + Red(ddlBuilding.SelectedValue);

        mail.Body += Bold("<br>Room Number: ") + Red(txtRoomNo.Text);

        mail.Body += Bold("<br>Administrator's Email: ") + Red(ddlAdministrator.SelectedValue);

        mail.Body += Bold("<br><br>Type of Request: ") + Red(rblRequestType.Text);

        mail.Body += Bold("<br>Device Requested: ") + Red(rblRequestDevice.Text);

        mail.Body += Bold("<br><br>Description of Request: ") + Red(txtDescription.Value);

        mail2.Body += Bold(content);

        mail2.Body += "</span>";

        try
        {
            server.Send(mail2);
            ErrorAlert("Request successfully submitted, if you do not receive a confirmation email please check the address and try again.");
            ClearInputs(Page.Controls);
        }
        catch (Exception E)
        {
            ErrorAlert(E.Message);
        }

        conn.Close();

        Response.Redirect("Process.aspx?id=" + id, false);

    }
    void ClearInputs(ControlCollection ctrls)
    {
        foreach (System.Web.UI.Control ctrl in ctrls)
        {
            if (ctrl is System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox)
            {
                ((System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox)ctrl).Text = string.Empty;
            }
            else if (ctrl is DropDownList)
            {
                ((DropDownList)ctrl).ClearSelection();
            }

            ClearInputs(ctrl.Controls);
        }
    }

    private String Red(String str)
    {
        string redstr = "<font color=\"red\">" + str + "</font>";
        return redstr;
    }

    private String Bold(String str)
    {
        string boldstr = "<b>" + str + "</b>";
        return boldstr;
    }

    private void ErrorAlert(String fieldname)
    {
        Type cstype = this.GetType();

        // Get a ClientScriptManager reference from the Page class.
        ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;

        // Check to see if the startup script is already registered.
        if (!cs.IsStartupScriptRegistered(cstype, "PopupScript"))
        {
            String cstext = "alert('" + fieldname + "');";
            cs.RegisterStartupScript(cstype, "PopupScript", cstext, true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are calling `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` then using `cmd.ExecuteScalar()` so the sql will be executed twice.

Comment: thank you @Haldo! I didn't look at the ExecuteScalar method I will study it. I took out the ExecuteNonQuery and there is no duplicate entry on submission now.

Answer (score 1):

@Haldo is correct. There are some other issues with your code that you should address though. First, and most serious, is your use of raw user input in your SQL insert. Never insert user input into your database without doing something to ensure that you are not accepting malicious code. The first thing I would recommend you should consider doing is using paramterized queries.

```
var query = "INSERT INTO Requests (
        RequestDate, RequestorsName, RequestorsEmail, BuildingName, 
        BuildingRoom, AdministratorEmail, RequestType, RequestDevice, 
        RequestDescription) 
        OUTPUT INSERTED.ID VALUES 
        ( @today, @requestor, @email, @building, @room, @admin, 
            @requestType, @requestDevice, @description
        )";

using (var connection = new SqlConnection("connectionstring")){
    using (var command = new SqlCommand(query, connection)){
        command.Parameters.AddWithValues("today", dtToday);
        ...

        var result = command.ExecuteScalar();
    }
}
```

Once you parameterize your queries you should consider splitting that method into smaller chunks, say one method to take care of the email, and another for the insert operation.

Comment: thanks @crunchy I will certainly work on that!

Comment: thanks again for this recommendation. Using parameterized queries really helped!